# find out type/value of x in lambda x while using apply/pipe

Tags: python, debugging, lambda

I'm still running in errors when trying to write code where I use pipe/lambda on Series/Dataframes so I wondered if there is a way to debug my code to get better understanding.
Just a simple example:
I have a Series:

```
s = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50])
```

If I want to add some number to each element I could use:

```
s.apply(lambda x : x+5)
#or
s.pipe(lambda x : x+5)
```

both works fine.
But if I want to use conditional lambda:

```
s.apply(lambda x : x+5 if x>20 else 0) # works

s.pipe(lambda x : x+5 if x>20 else 0) # doesn't work
```

I get ValueError, the truth of a Series is ambiguous. If I wouldn't know why I get the error here I would need to know what `x` is...
This is just an example, it's NOT about how to get the conditional adding done. I just want to know what is happening there and therefore I need to know what is `x` while executing my code.

Here is my question. When working on more complex matters and running into errors, is there a way I can debug my code to get to know the type or value of the `x` at any moment in the lambda while executing the code? For example a print statement?  It would help to understand why I fail sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This case:*

The difference is that the `x` in `apply` is a *single* element of the Series, since the lambda function is applied to all elements one after the other. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
Parameters:
   func, function: Function to apply to each column or row.
```

In the case of `pipe`, the `x` is the series itself, which is why the conditional lambda doesn't work (`if x>20` doesn't make sense). This is evident from the `pipe` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
Parameters:
    func, function: Function to apply to the Series/DataFrame.
```

*General debugging:*

Define a function instead of using a lambda expression, then you can add print statements as you desire:

```
def my_func(x):
    print(x)
    return x+5 if x>20 else 0


s.pipe(my_func)
```

Comment: This case is clear to me, it was just for the purpose of explaining my question, but thanks. To the debugging: Wow this was so obvious, I feel a little embarrassed now :D Thanks! When working on DataFrames, working along axis=0 or axis=1 I often have to think twice what the lambda takes as input, now I can easily debug it with a little func if having problems